# How can I double space a document in LibreOffice?

Tags: styles, libreoffice-writer, text-formatting

A text file of a few pages and several paragraphs was read into LibreOffice Writer and needs to be double spaced throughout the document. The sequence:

> Format -> paragraph -> Indents & Spacing -> Line spacing -> Double

affects only the paragraph where the cursor is positioned. Searching the web and help has not turned up a way to double space the document. (Although I'm certain I've done it before. Alas, I've got CRS (Can't Remember Stuff) syndrome.)

Comment: Select all the paragraphs first. Then right click > format paragraph ...

Answer (score 4):

#### How can I double space a document in LibreOffice?

1. Select all the paragraphs (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>)
2. Right click and select "Paragraph"
3. Select "Indents & Spacing"
4. Set "Line Spacing" to "Double" and click "OK"
5. Change "Below paragraph" as well if you want extra spacing **between** paragraphs.

   [image]

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Changing the (default) style is IMHO the better option - otherwise, after inserting a new heading and a new text paragraph afterwards, the text paragraph will have normal spacing (i assume).

Comment: <shrug>. OP didn't say he was going to add more text to the document.

Comment: OK - no objections  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Two options...

1. Brute force... `Edit -> Select All`, or `Ctrl+a`, then change the paragraph settings (as you've indicated) to make everything double spaced.
2. Change the style... `Format -> Styles and Formatting` (v5.0.x) or `View -> Styles and Formatting` (v5.1.x), then right-click on the style you use, which applies to the paragraphs (normally `Text Body`), and change the `Indents & Spacing`.

Comment: When I tried method 2, I needed to select all beforehand, or it only worked on one paragraph.

Comment: In LibreOffice 5.x, it's Menu `View` -> `Styles and Formatting` (or use F11 to bring up the `Styles and Formatting` box).

Comment: @GreenMatt, you shouldn't need to select all, if you're changing styles.  Try changing the "`Default Style`".  I do this a lot, where I have paragraphs separated by headings, tables, and other content, and I can change just the paragraph formatting by changing the style.  @tohuwawohu, that's strange, I have a different menu layout, and I'm using LibreOffice 5.0.3.2 (on ubuntu/mint).

Comment: In fact, that's strange. I'm using 5.1.x on Ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe it's because you've moved up to the 16.x ubuntu (I'm still on a 14.04 base).  I've just upgraded manually to LibreOffice 5.1.x and I can confirm they have changed the menus.  In 5.1.x, `Styles` are indeed under **`View`**.